# Where to set GOPATH after installing go using brew?

Tags: oauth, go, linuxbrew

I installed Go on my ubuntu 14.04 using Linux brew and then I have set `GOPATH` to `$HOME/go`. But after that i tried to install goauth package for go using go get command but still my code is not importing goauth package. After going through the error I decided to check the `GOPATH`. It is properly set but the goauth package is not getting installed in `$HOME/go/src/code.google.com/p`. Please suggest me a work around. Here is the error that I am getting.

```
dummy.go:5:8: cannot find package "code.google.com/p/goauth2/oauth" in any of:
    /home/avinash/.linuxbrew/Cellar/go/1.4.2/libexec/src/code.google.com/p/goauth2/oauth (from $GOROOT)
    /home/avinash/go/src/code.google.com/p/goauth2/oauth (from $GOPATH)
go/src/github.com/google/go-github/github/github.go:22:2: cannot find package "github.com/google/go-querystring/query" in any of:
    /home/avinash/.linuxbrew/Cellar/go/1.4.2/libexec/src/github.com/google/go-querystring/query (from $GOROOT)
    /home/avinash/go/src/github.com/google/go-querystring/query (from $GOPATH)
```

Comment: If you look at https://code.google.com/p/goauth2/ you'll see that you probably want `golang.org/x/oauth2`.

Comment: That said, `go get code.google.com/p/goauth2/oauth` does work for me.

Comment: Yes. I did look into the package in their official github page and it was indeed golang.org/x/oauth2.Thanks @DaveC

Comment: @DaveC Now even i tried running go get for oauth but it now gives me a very common problem of mercurial not being installed.Is Google planning to move such packages from mercurial version control to github ant time soon

Comment: In general, if you expect `go get <random import>` to work you need at minimum git and mecurial installed, probably bzr too as there are a couple of well used packages on launchpad.